# How to check if used paginate in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I have a custom view and in some functions, I used `paginate` and other functions I don't use `paginate`. now how can I check if I used `paginate` or not ?

```
@if($products->links())

   {{$products->links()}}

@endif // not work
```

of course that I know I can use a variable as true false to will check it, But is there any native function to check it ?

Comment: Can you try this? `{!! $products->links() !!}`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This works perfectly. Check if `$products` is an instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` then display the pagination links.

```
@if($products instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator )

   {{$products->links()}}

@endif
```

Comment: The best way is the method $products->hasMorePages()

Comment: Keep in mind that the length aware paginator is different from the simple paginator (that does not count the total number of pages). For that, check for an instance of `\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`. Both extrend `\Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator` so that can be used to catch either.

Answer (score 31):

```
@if($threads->hasPages())
  {{ $threads->links() }}
@endif
```

Simple one!

Comment: I had my pagination links inside a container but sometimes there were not enough results to generate pages. This solved it!

Answer (score 9):

Try like this

```
@if($products instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator)

   {{$products->links()}}

@endif
```

You need to check wheater the `$products` is instance of `Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator`. It can be an array or Laravel's `Collection` as well.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' `

Comment: What php version you have?

Comment: I am using Laravel Homestead. PHP Version 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: Hmm... thats strange. You can try: 'Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator' instead of `\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::class` but the PHP ver alows that. Maybe you get this error somewhere else?

Comment: Now am getting an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`.

Comment: OK I'm sory.... when you doing `instanceof` you should past the classname just like this: `\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`. I've reedit my entry.

Comment: Tried it. The pagination links are not displaying, meaning it returned `false`

Comment: It seems Laravel changed the class to `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`

Comment: It's better to check: `Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator`

Answer (score 7):

The beautiful way:

```
@if ($products->hasMorePages())
    {{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```

[Click here to see the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

Comment: Last page will hide the pagination links

Answer (score 7):

As of laravel 7 you can now do this:

```
@if( $vehicles->hasPages() )
   {{ $vehicles->links() }}
@endif
```

Comment: This was [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367834/1255289) as an answer 18 months prior.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a check on the base class of the variable. This could lead to problems with changing base classes in future Laravel versions. Simply check whether the method links exists:

```
@if(method_exists($products, 'links'))
   {{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
@if (class_basename($products) !== 'Collection')
   {{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```

You can use PHP function: get_class($products) - to get full class name.
Laravel should have some function to check ->paginate() is in use.

Answer (score 0):

- just write `paginate(0)` instead of `get()`
- Blade Template: simply use `{{$products->links}}`. no `@if @endif` needed.

Answer (score 0):

laravel paginate have 2 type :

- simplePaginate() will return \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
- paginate() will return Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator

Based on the above conditions, you can try this solution :

```
@if(
    $products instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator ||
    $products instanceof Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
  )
 {{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use $products->paginate(); in the Controller, you will always have an instance of ***\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator*** in the view.

If you want to check if the pagination is actually used:

```
@if($products->previousPageUrl() || $products->nextPageUrl())

   {{ $products->links() }}

@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Corrected code (add "isset"):

```
@if(isset($products->links()))

   {{$products->links()}}

@endif
```

Shorter version:

```
{{$products->links() ?? ''}}
```

It will work for paginate, simplePaginate and when there is no pagination. The solution with "$products->hasMorePages()" will not display pagination links on the last page.

Comment: 6 answer before you... explain why to use yours... instead of others.

Comment: You can use `isset` only with variables and arrays. The shorter version is also incorrect, for non-existing methods it will through an error.

Answer (score -1):

Juse use below format

```php
@if($products instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator )

   {{$products->links()}}

@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@if($products->currentPage() > 1)

   {{$products->links()}}

@endif
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

check if products are instance of Pagination

```
@if($products instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)
        {{ $products->links() }}
@endif
```