# Laravel - Error: Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to export to excel using PHP 7, Laravel 5.8, Maatwebsite Excel 3.1. I successfully display on the view blade and also perform the filter.

Model:

`use App\UserResponse;`

**Controller**

```php
public function userresponseReport(Request $request,$export=false)
{
    $data['title'] = 'User Response';

    $userresponses = DB::table('user_response as g')
        ->select(
            //DB::raw('DATE(g.created_at) as created_date'),
            DB::raw('g.created_at as created_date'),
            'g.msisdn', 
            'g.game_code', 
            'g.answer',
            'g.answer_code',
            'g.Amount_charged',
            'g.payment_ref',
            'g.status',
            'g.user_channel'                
        )               
        ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC'); 

    $start_date = $request->start_date;
    $end_date = $request->end_date; 

    $render=[];  
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $userresponses = $userresponses->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date.' 00:00:00',$end_date.' 23:59:59']);
        $render['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
        $render['end_date'] = $request->end_date;
    } elseif(isset($request->start_date)) {
        $userresponses = $userresponses->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
        $render['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
    }

    if(isset($request->msisdn))
    {
        $userresponses = $userresponses->where('msisdn','like','%'.$request->msisdn.'%');
        $render['msisdn'] = $request->msisdn;
    }

    if(isset($request->game_code))
    {
        $userresponses = $userresponses->where('game_code','like','%'.$request->game_code.'%');
        $render['game_code'] = $request->game_code;
    }   

    if(isset($request->user_channel))
    {
        $userresponses = $userresponses->where('user_channel','like','%'.$request->user_channel.'%');
        $render['user_channel'] = $request->user_channel;
    }

    if(!empty($export))
    {
        return Excel::download(new UserresponseExport($userresponses->get()), 'userresponse.xlsx');
    }        
    $userresponses = $userresponses->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $userresponses = $userresponses->paginate(15);
    $userresponses = $userresponses->appends($render);
    $data['userresponses'] = $userresponses;

    return view('report.userresponseReport',$data);        
}
```

Then after that, the view blade:

`userresponseReport.blade.php`

```php
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('msisdn',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'MSISDN']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('game_code',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Game Code']) }}
        </div>   
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('user_channel',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Channel']) }}
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{ Form::date('start_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{ Form::date('end_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
        </div>          
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
            <a href="{{ route('userresponseReport',['export']) }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>


<div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condesed" id="commenter_info_table">
                <caption></caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>MSISDN</td>
                        <td>Game Code</td>
                        <td>Game Name</td>
                        <td>Answer</td>
                        <td>Channel</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($userresponses as $key => $userresponse)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
            <!--                <td>{{ $userresponse->created_date }}</td>-->
                            <td>{{ date('Y-m-d h:i:s A', strtotime($userresponse->created_date)) }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $userresponse->msisdn }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $userresponse->game_code }}</td>
                            <td> 
                                @if($userresponse->game_code=='101')
                                   Trivia
                                @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='102')
                                   Predict and Win 
                                @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='103')
                                   Party With the BBN 
                                @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='104')
                                   Grand Prize  
                                @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='105')
                                   Happy Hour    
                                @elseif($userresponse->game_code=='106')
                                   Power Boost                         
                                @endif                       
                            </td>                
                            <td>{{ $userresponse->answer }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $userresponse->user_channel }}</td>                                    
                        </tr>          
                    @endforeach
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="14">
                            {{ $userresponses->links() }}
                        </td>
                        </tr>         
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Then the Export

`UserresponseExport`

```php
class UserresponseExport implements FromView, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents, WithMapping
{
    protected $userresponses;

    public function __construct($userresponses = null)
    {
        $this->userresponses = $userresponses;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        return view('report.userresponseReport', [
            'userresponses' => $this->userresponses ?: DB::table('user_response as g')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('g.created_at as created_date'),
                    'g.msisdn', 
                    'g.game_code', 
                    'g.answer',
                    'g.answer_code',
                    'g.Amount_charged',
                    'g.payment_ref',
                    'g.status',
                    'g.user_channel'                
                )             
            ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC')
        ]);
    } 

    private $headings = [
        'Date Created',
        'MSISDN',
        'game_code',
        'Answer',
        'Channel'
    ]; 

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headings;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $cellRange = 'A1:E1'; // All headers
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
            },
        ];
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/report/userresponse-report/{export?}', ['as' => 'userresponseReport', 'uses' => 'ReportController@userresponseReport']);
```

On the view blade, when I clicked on search everything was okay. But when I click on export, I got this error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bbnaijareport\resources\views\report\userresponseReport.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions
>   Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist. (0)

[image: excel_report_error]

How do I resolve this issue?

new error
[image: new_error]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are displaying the pagination in the `userresponseReport.blade.php`, but you didn't load it in the export part. So either have the export function also paginated or built in a check around the links:

```
@if($userresponses instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator )
    <tr>
        <td colspan="14">
            {{ $userresponses->links() }}
        </td>
    </tr>  
@endif
```

[Credits to Richie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977760/how-to-check-if-used-paginate-in-laravel)

Comment: I did as you advised, but I got a new error. I updated my code with the snapshot called new_error.   Also see the summary:                    "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$created_date (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bbnaijareport\resources\views\report\userresponseReport.blade.php)

Comment: @user11352561 it is common to post a new question when these kind of things happen (a new error after the previous was fixed), but I'll answer it in this comment anyway: You have two totally different queries for the userresponses and use the same view to export the data as to show it to the user. Make sure you either have the same data or have a seperate view for the export.

Comment: Thats what led me to trying to Export view. I had tried having separate views but was exporting everything and not the filtered data data. Is there a way you can help me out. I've been on it for long

Comment: @user11352561 Yeah sure! The best solution (in my opinion) would be to move the data retrieval (the part where you get everything out the database and start the pagination and stuff) to a single method. This helps you by getting the exact same data to both the display and the export method. DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself. If you're using the same code twice or more times, make a separate part for it.

Comment: @user11352561 So in this case: Make a separate file (file 1) where you retrieve the `userresponses ` and use the code from the normal controller (file 2). If you have done this, retrieve the data from that file (file 1) in the controller (file 2) and push it to the view. In the export class (file 3), remove the part where you retrieve the data from the database and call that newly created file (file 1). This will fix the errors.